# Get capture groups from a conditional REGEX

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I want to write a conditional regex which matches 1 of 2 patterns.

To do that, I have a simple conditional:

`/((pattern1)|(pattern2))/gi`

Problem is, within pattern1, I may have multiple capture groups -- lets say 3 of them, but within pattern2, I have 5 of them.

**How can I tell WHICH of the 2 patterns matched?** I need to be able to request the proper capture groups (by number) for my output.

I guess in my example you could just check for the existence of any capture group value above 3, but say I had an equal amount of capture groups in each pattern.  I'm thinking there must be a good way to do this -- I'm using PHP or JavaScript.  Let me know if more details are needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just use two regexes =D

Comment: That's not a conditional, it's an alternation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The patterns are numbered based on the regex itself, not on the outcome of an actual match. In your example, the overall group will always be group 1, then the first possibility ("pattern1") will be group 2, and the other will be group 3.  If "pattern2" matches, then group 3 will be non-empty and group 2 will be empty, in other words. Group 1 will always be the same as the non-empty one of groups 2 and 3.

Comment: Ah, so you're saying that theoretically, pattern1 would always contain capture groups 2, 3, and 4 -- and pattern2 would always contain groups 5, 6, and 7 just based off how I wrote the regex??

Comment: Yes. What I've always done is count the groups by the position of the left paren in the regex. (I'm not 100% sure that's strictly correct, but I don't write too many super-complicated regular expressions.) So the group with the leftmost "(" is group 1, then the next "(" is group two, and so on.

Comment: Yes, that is the rule: the relative position of the opening paren is what determines the group number.  However, it's possible to override that behavior in some flavors, like with the branch-reset group that [sln](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8333398/20938) used.

Answer (score 0):

`(pattern1)` will be in match[1] if it was matched, match[1] will be `undefined` if it wasn't matched..  `(pattern2)` will be in match[2] if present, `undefined` if not.

The match array is defined from the regex itself without regard to what actually matched.  Those things that didn't get matched will be undefined in the array.

In this code:

```
var re = /(patt)(ern1)|(pat)(tern2)/i;
var str = "this is pattern1 and some more text";

var matches = str.match(re);
```

You get a matches array with five entries.

```
matches[0] === "pattern1"
matches[1] === "patt"
matches[2] === "ern1"
matches[3] === undefined
matches[4] === undefined
matches.length === 5
```

Note, this only works if you remove the outer capturing parens and the "g" flag you had in your match pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand trying out what you want to find in a console like firebug in Firefox this way:

```
'mystring'.replace(/myregex/gi, function () {
    console.info(arguments);
});
```

Like this you can just do some trial and error to see how the regex works. But be warned: the RegExp is not working the same cross browser in every case.

Answer (score 0):

"**How can I tell WHICH of the 2 patterns matched?** I need to be able to request the proper capture groups (by number) for my output."

If you don't know anything about the grouping in each pattern

`(?|(pattern1)|(pattern2))`

allows you to start the indexing at group 1.
But the significance of which pattern might still be a mystery. Better check content after that point.